# Conditionally calling 'collection_select' from a model/helper with AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looping through each instance of a built `sub-tournament` - and the problem that I'm having has to do with conditionally creating a `collection_select` box with data fetched via ajax.  Here's the view - the line I want to insert code in is marked:

**View**

```
<% @tournament.sub_tournaments.each_with_index do |sub, i| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :sub_tournaments, sub, :validate => false do |sub_form| %>
    <div class="tab-content standings-row-<%= i %>" style="display:none">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th> <h4>Standing</h4> </th>
            <th class="standings-field-<%= i %>"></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <%= sub_form.fields_for :standings, :validate => false do |standings| %>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %><%= f.text_field :standing, :class => "standing", readonly: true, :type => "" %>
              </td>
              <td class="standings-ajax-<%= i %>">**INSERT HERE**</td>
              <td><span class="remove">Remove</span></td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>  
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="add-item">
        <%= link_to_add_standings_fields(sub_form, :standings) %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I thought about doing the conditional check (it depends upon whether the game selected is a team game or a single-player game) in the controller, but it seems to make more sense as a method (or a helper?).  At the moment I have it in `Standing.rb` (below) - but I'm getting a `no method "collection_select"` error - so probably form helpers aren't available in models, which seems reasonable.  So how could I do this?

**Standing.rb**

```
def team_or_player(game)
  if Game::TEAM_GAMES.include?(game.name)
    self.collection_select(:team_division_id, TeamDivision.where("game_id = ?", game.id), 
                                :id, :name, {include_blank: true})
  else
    self.collection_select(:player_id, Player.where("game_id = ?", game.id), 
                                :id, :handle, {include_blank: true})
  end
end
```

And how can I pass the `f` to my AJAX call?

**AJAX**

```
$(".standings-ajax-<%= @tab_number %>").html("<%= ** ?? **.team_or_player(@standing, @game) %>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call helper in model:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.collection_select( ... )
```

So from what I can see you should change `team_or_player()` to class method and call it with:

```
Standings.team_or_player(@standing, @game)
```

or as instance

```
@standing.team_or_player(@standing, @game)
```

But that you should use `self` instead of passing `@standing`.

Me preference would be to put that logic directly in view or to helper.

Comment: i ended up putting it in application_helper - but the `ActionController::Base.helpers.collection_select()` is useful, even if it should have been obvious to me :p  +1 thanks!